# Erro ao executar o composer update ao tentar instalar o package scafold no Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Eu estou tentando instalar o package scafold no Laravel 5.1 só que quando executo o composer update ele me mostra um erro.

> C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\estoque>composer update Loading composer
>   repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including
>   require-dev)
>
> [ErrorException] zlib_decode(): data error
>
> update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]
>   [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plu gins] [--no-custom-installers]
>   [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no- progress] [--with-de
>   pendencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
>   [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--p refer-stable] [--prefer-lowest]
>   [packages1] ... [packagesN]

Então eu executei o comando composer -vvv update:

> Downloading
>   http://packagist.org/p/laravel/framework$4721af190d059e42de5d516c963b992ca7e16
>   55071f2f84cfaf1fc7fcfa54b8e.json
>
> [ErrorException] zlib_decode(): data error
>
> Exception trace: () at 
>   phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFi
>   les ystem.php:218

Creio que seja erro no Laravel...
Eu já atualizei o composer, já verifiquei se o composer.phar está sem o utf8 - bom e também se o zlib do PHP está ativado.

composer.json:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "bestmomo/scafold": "0.0.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "estoque\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece ser um erro de conexão.

Tente remover a pasta vendor e o arquivo composer.lock e depois instalar novamente.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta alterar o seu `composer.json` no seguinte trecho

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "bestmomo/scafold": "dev-master" // estava como 0.0.1
},
```

e em seguida faça o update

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente limpar o cache:

```
$ composer clearcache
```